# What register points to the heap?

Tags: c++, assembly, arm, heap-memory

I just finished learning ARM architecture/assembly. If the SP register holds the address of the next memory location to put data into, what holds the address of the heap? For example in C++ if you declare an object on the heap (e.g. `MyObj example = new MyObj();`) what would the assembly look like, in the sense where would it know where `example` is?

Comment: That's an implementation detail of the compiler.  http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-07/Ferguson/Whitepaper/bh-usa-07-ferguson-WP.pdf

Comment: Registers are for things the CPU needs to know about.  There's a SP register because the CPU has special hardware that automatically does things with the stack (for example saving context when an interrupt happens).  The CPU doesn't know or care about the heap.

Comment: heap is not a hardware thing, the stack is. heep and allocation within the heap are related to the language and libraries (have nothing to do with the hardware).

Comment: @TJD: On ARM nothing is saved on the stack by the hardware. The CPU will rename registers to switch to an interrupt context. In the 32-bit ARM ISA SP is just an alias for R13. And in fact it's "only" ABI specified to be used as a stack pointer.

Comment: Depending on the language there might be more than one pointer to a heap or even none. So asking what register contains the pointer to the heap is point(er)less

Comment: @Masta79, of course hardware is putting things on the stack.  For example, Cortex M3 automatically writes 8 registers to the stack when an exception happens.  Some ARMs have multiple stacks that cause SP to get remapped/renamed, but the point is that HW is still using those registers to do very specific things.

Comment: *I just finished learning ...* Most amusing phrase I've seen all week. :P

Comment: @PeterCordes haha yes that's funny I would say that. I was taking a course at the time and the prof explained how ARM is better than x86 as it can be mastered in a few months.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack in this context is a lower level structure provided by OS/EABI. That's why there is a conventional register for that. However, heap is a higher level structure provided by OS. So managing and playing with it depends on the agreement with your app and OS. In assembly terms, you'll be using that heap with dereferencing some addresses through registers.

Comment: Ok so you're saying at the CPU level there isn't really a concept of heap?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Any memory you are playing (read/write) with must be allowed for you to do so. That's where OS helps, you either allocate some memory by malloc or your app already tells OS how much memory it needs in executable binary. Then when you are using that memory, you start dereferencing registers containing addresses of areas that you are allowed to play with.

Comment: On ARM there also is nothing like real hardware support for stacks. It's very different to x86 in that regard. The CPU itself does not really know what "stack" is. And you also require OS-Support for the stack-area, because the kernel has to grow your stack if required.

Comment: @Masta79, +1. There is no support from CPU for stacks, It's the EABI which tells how the stack grows, which register to use etc and even then you can locally scratch the stack register for functions which move large chunks of memory (register pressure being too high and/or multiple register load/store leading to higher bandwidth) etc..

Comment: Yes, I actually agree that it is not provided by CPU and instead it is OS/EABI. What I thought was usage of pop/push through assembly and it felt much easier to pop up the CPU word. I'll update my answer now. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: @NicoErfurth: According to [this documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/Babefdjc.html) ARM does implicitly use "the stack" for exception handling, so it's no different from x86 in that respect.  It's easier to avoid using SP explicitly for call/return on ARM than on x86, but that can be done on x86.  (emulate jump-with-link by using a RIP-relative LEA to store a return address in a register, then JMP.  Return with a register-indirect jump.  push and pop are easy to emulate using other instructions, so you could use any other reg as a callstack ptr.)

Answer (score 6):

The SP register is normally used to track the current position within the stack. This means it pretty much needs to always point to the stack.

The same cannot be said for the heap. When you need to access a variable, the address of that variable will be stored either in a pointer or other memory reference from your app. At the time that address is needed, a register could be used to make the reference. But the details of which register is not only compiler dependent but is also likely to depend on which register is available after code is optimized from the same compiler.

Comment: Come to think of it why is register 15 (or whatever it is for ARM) the SP? Why not any register? Is it some how faster?

Comment: Why not SP? The stack requires a dedicated register that's affected by calls and returns, and that register is SP.

Comment: But what's the difference. You need a dedicated register for stacks but not heaps?

Comment: R15 is the PC, R14 LR and R13 is SP. Keeping the stack pointer in a register is just a very convenient way for function to allocate temporary space. Which is very often required. Otherwise you would need some global storage  for every little piece of memory you want to work with, which can become a real performance problem.

Comment: @Celeritas the answer to your question about why `r13` is used as the stack pointer is partly convention, and partly the fact that ARM CPUs have a subset of registers that are shadowed in IRQ and FIQ modes  - both interrupt modes which need to be fast and require separate stacks.

If fact, on a system with full memory protection such as Linux, this isn't much of a concern, so the choice is entirely convention.

Comment: @Celeritas: Yes, I tried to explain that in my answer. Addresses in the heap will be stored in variables or directly in the application. They will be retrieved when needed, and so there is no need to always have a register with this value. In fact, the heap can have billions of addresses so it doesn't even make sense to always have a register with a heap address.

Answer (score 2):

The processor needs a special register for the stack pointer because sometimes (an interrupt or exception) the processor hardware must modify the SP directly, without executing any code. That's not necessary for the heap, so there is no need to use a special register to point to the heap. At runtime the OS decides where a particular chunk of code can store things on the heap, and any register can be used to hold that address.

Answer (score 0):

In ARM's EABI, R13 (SP) points to the last pushed data on full descending stack. However it is not necessary to be pointing to that at all times, such code can be legal:

Considering r0 to be pointing to a valid memory location accessible by our program.

```
stmfd r0!, {r1-r12, sp, lr}
ldr   r1, [r0]
mov   r2, lr
sub   lr, sp, #4
str   sp, [r4]
add   sp, lr, #4
ldmfd r0!, {r1-r12, sp, pc}
```

ofcourse it doesn't make sense, but it's only point was that if you can safely reload sp, lr and all the other callee saved registers, you can scratch them as much as you want while remembering to restore their values before returning to the caller.

Another point, Stack and heap may not necessarily be the same, heap is a higher level abstract for malloc/free type constructs whereas stack is used for saving callee registers when just 4 registers are not enough or used to pass function arguments, data structures and all you can imagine but stack is a bit harder to manage because you have to keep track of all the data by yourself instead of just allocating region to a pointer and then freeing it after you're done.

Usually depending on the program and environment you can use various hacks and stuff for optimisations such as knowingly corrupt some non-scratch registers and get away with it, however you will have to manage that in your caller function and it should be aware of the registers that will be scratched in subsequent function calls, hence EABI may only make sense when transferring control to another program or taking over, you can do what you like in your time on cpu, just make sure to leave it as clean as it was before you entered the place.

Comment: Having SP temporarily not pointing at valid stack space is only safe in user-space with no signal-handlers installed or any other mechanism that could asynchronously use the stack pointer.  (Or in kernel mode with interrupts disabled).  Otherwise, handling a signal or interrupt respectively will scribble over whatever SP was pointing at, or fault if it wasn't a valid pointer at all.  (Or do some ARM versions use banked registers for interrupt context, so it doesn't rely on the current kernel stack pointer?)